# Chrome: change sync settings BEFORE syncing

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I only want to sync bookmarks. Unless I'm mistaken, though, the moment I sign into chrome for the first time, it immediately syncs everything, including history and passwords. This is a profoundly stupid thing to do. I should be able to choose what to sync BEFORE syncing. Is this possible? If it isn't, then I'm just going to have to avoid chrome sync altogether.